# flutter: error: A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'

Tags: flutter, dart, notnull

i have a class in flutter:

```
class Perguntas{
  String? questao;
  bool? respostaDaQuestao;

  Perguntas ({String? q, bool? r }){
    questao = q;
    respostaDaQuestao = r;
  }
}
```

and in the main class:

```
<Perguntas> bancoDePerguntas = [
  Perguntas(q: 'O metrô é um dos meios de transporte mais seguros do mundo', r: true),
  Perguntas(q: 'A culinária brasileira é uma das melhores do mundo.',r: true),
  Perguntas(q: 'Vacas podem voar, assim como peixes utilizam os pés para andar.', r: false)
];
questaoAtual = 0;

Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
               bool resultado = bancoDePerguntas[questaoAtual].respostaDaQuestao;
```

in the bool resultado = bancoDePerguntas[questaoAtual].respostaDaQuestao; the error appears: error: A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'.
how do i solve this?

display the answer if it was true or false from the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ? to bool like this:

```
bool? resultado = bancoDePerguntas[questaoAtual].respostaDaQuestao;
```

The reason behind this is that respostaDaQuestao has or will have a bool? and the variable receiving that variable will also have to be bool?,

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
bool? resultado = bancoDePerguntas[questaoAtual].respostaDaQuestao;
```

or

```
bool resultado = bancoDePerguntas[questaoAtual].respostaDaQuestao!;
```